# How to find a minimum Value from a category made from "summarise()" fuction?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1990)
therm %>% 
  rep_sample_n(size = 30, reps = 1000) %>%
  summarise(Avg_police = mean(ft_police, na.rm = TRUE),)
```

here I am making 1000 samples of 30. everything above worked normally and I got a summary of the average of 'ft_police' value for each 1000 sample.

Now I am trying to figure out the lowest average of 'ft_police' estimated in my sample

I tried adding min() but didnt work...

since Im trying to find a minimum number from a column made from summarise(), none of the things I learned before works. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce your issue.
Else, we can only guess what you're up to. My guess would be that:

```
require("dplyr") # You should include what packages you import, else others cannot run your code or have to figure out by themselfes
require("infer")

# Here you should define your variable therm (we don't have that data)
therm <- <some stuff>

therm %>% 
  rep_sample_n(size = 30, reps = 1000) %>%
  group_by(replicate) %>%
  summarise(
    Avg_police = mean(ft_police, na.rm = TRUE),
    Min_police = min(ft_police, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
```

should work.

If this answer does not address your question properly, you need to pose the question properly. If you provide more information, I will probably come back and adjust this answer accordingly. Please read through the page I linked to improve your question. In R, you can use `dput()` to print your data.frame in a way others can copy and paste it to use it. Of course, it would be reasonable to only apply that to a minimal subset of your data.frame. Alternatively, you could provide code to create a generic data set similar to the one you are using. E.g.

```
therm <- data.frame(ft_police = runif(100))
```

This example (including generating an example data set) works:

```
packages <- c("dplyr", "infer")

for(i in 1:NROW(packages)){
  if(!require(
    packages[i], character.only = TRUE
  )){
    install.packages(
      packages[i],
      dependencies = TRUE
    )
    require(
      packages[i],
      character.only = TRUE
    )
  }
}

set.seed(1990)

therm <- data.frame(ft_police = runif(100))

therm %>% 
  rep_sample_n(size = 30, reps = 1000) %>%
  group_by(replicate) %>%
  summarise(
    Avg_police = mean(ft_police, na.rm = TRUE),
    Min_police = min(ft_police, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
```